# Installing Bumblebee - Kernel issues

Tags: 12.04, drivers, kernel, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I'm fairly new to Linux and I'm currently running Linux Mint 13 (based on Ubuntu 12.04). I'm trying to install Bumblebee with preferably the latest stable Nvidia 319 drivers on my Asus R505CB ([this](http://www.asus.com/au/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/R505CB/#specifications) specs, but with GT740M instead of the GT635M).

I've been trying a lot of things the past two days without succes. With Nouveau only the integrated graphics are working and when I install any version of the nVidia driver (both via the nVidia website and PPA's) Cinnamon can't start and I get this error when I start NVIDIA X Server Settings:

> You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver.  Please edit your X
>   configuration file (just run `nvidia-xconfig` as root), and restart
>   the X server.

Now, trying to install Bumblebee once again I see I apparently overlooked this line on this [wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation):

> If on 12.04.3, replace linux-headers-generic with 
>   linux-headers-generic-lts-raring.

How do I do this? I have currently installed the 3.12 Linux kernel (had 3.2, which was default).

1) I guess I have to use this 3.8 kernel instead of the 3.12 version to make bumblebee work?

2) When I tried installing it, it installed these packages:

> linux-headers-generic-lts-raring
>
> linux-image-3.8.0-33-generic
>
> linux-image-generic-lts-raring

But it doesn't place a .bin file in the /boot folder so when i run sudo update-grub it wouldn't detect this 3.8 kernel and I'm still using the 3.2 version with which I can't get the Bumblebee daemon started.

What to do?

I'm sure I forgot to say something... :p

Thanks in advance,

Comment: what was the output of `uname -r`.If you install linux 3.8 kernel, it must be in `/usr/src` folder.

Comment: is that 3.8 kernal is in `/usr/src` folder.

Comment: "uname -r" gives output: "3.2.0-56-generic" and in the folder "/usr/src" are these folders: "linux-headers-3.8.0-33", "linux-headers-3.8.0-33-generic" and "nvidia-319-319.49".

Comment: When I run "sudo update-grub" I get this:<br/>"<br/>Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub<br/>
Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default<br/>
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst<br/>
Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...<br/>
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-56-generic<br/>
Found kernel: /boot/memtest86+.bin<br/>
Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done<br/>
"

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade/142000#142000 it would help you to update kernal.

Comment: Okay, I installed "v3.8.13.12-raring" and when I run "sudo update-grub" the 3.8 version is there, but in grub I can only see the 3.2 version where I can boot from, and "uname -a" also indicates that I'm still running the 3.2 version (after a restart of course).

Answer (score 0):

Run the below command to update your kernal,

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

After installation,reboot your pc.

Comment: Thanks, but that is just the 3.2 version of the Linux Kernel... Right?